# issues regarding radio buttons in an existing Sencha form

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

I am working with an existing Sencha form that declares variables like this

```
    var UserForm_blahblah = Ext.create('YesNoCombo',{
     name:"UserForm_blahblah",
     fieldLabel: "Blah Blah Blah
     inputValue: "UserForm_blahblah"
 });
```

Then later the variables are called in specific sections like this,
         UserForm_blahblah,

I am attempting to creat radio buttons like this:

```
   var UserForm_yaddayadda = Ext.create('Ext.form.Radio',{
        name:"UserForm_yaddayadda",
        fieldLabel:'Yadda Yadda',
        inputValue: "UserForm_yaddayadda
 });
```

when UserForm_yaddayadda is called, the variables are being passed correctly to the php processing form and email form.

Here are the issues:

1. I can't seem to set the variables in a multi-column format on this form. 
   It is all one column.
2. When I try to use radiogroup as in the Sencha example on their website, the radiogroup displays outside the panel I want the radiogroup to show up in.

I don't know if you want the code, because it is a very long form.

umbregachoong

Comment: A jsfiddle / printscreen / url links may help to understand the problem better.

Comment: Solved it. Sorry for taking up time. I set up a var UserForm_Companies = Ext.create('Ext.form.RadioGroup'{ as explained here: http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.form.RadioGroup.1/viewer.html.  Got rid of the renderTo:Ext.getBody() and the radiogroup worked within the panel. Just have to test now if the variables are being passed to the form.